# mailer with gmail gives Net::SMTPAuthenticationError: with 2-factor auth disabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, email, gmail, actionmailer

I am getting a `Net::SMTPAuthenticationError` both on my development (local) env as well as when I host on Heroku, when I try to send mails from my rails application.

This started after sending the first couple of email (2 mails to be specific).

All research so far made me think that this should could be due to having a `2-factor auth` enabled on the gmail account, but when I checked the account, `2-factor autt` was not enabled.

[image: screenshot of the 2-factor auth setting on my account]

below is my smtp setting both in `config/development.rb` and `config/production.rb`:

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  # SMTP settings for gmail
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
      :port                 => 587,
      :user_name            => Rails.configuration.gmail_address,
      :password             => Rails.configuration.gmail_password,
      :authentication       => "plain",
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

My mailer is set up as follow:

```
class StackoMailer < ActionMailer::Base

    def success_mail
      @my_email = Rails.configuration.gmail_address
      mail(
        from: 'notifications@StackoProbe.com',
        to: @my_email,
        subject: 'Fuck Yeah! Visited successfully...'
      )
    end
end
```

On calling `PushWatir::StackoMailer.success_mail.deliver_now!`, I get the following error:

```
2.2.1 :001 > PushWatir::StackoMailer.success_mail.deliver_now!
Net::SMTPAuthenticationError: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbv8i

    from /Users/andela/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:976:in `check_auth_response'
    from /Users/andela/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:740:in `auth_plain'
    from /Users/andela/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:732:in `authenticate'
    from /Users/andela/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:567:in `do_start'
    from /Users/andela/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:520:in `start'
    from /Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mail-2.6.3/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:112:in `deliver!'
    from /Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/mail-2.6.3/lib/mail/message.rb:252:in `deliver!'
    from /Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/actionmailer-4.2.4/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:77:in `deliver_now!'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/andela/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2.2.1 :002 >
```

What could be causing this?

How can I make this work? Big thanks for responses

Comment: Maybe check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25872863/199712) and its second comment? Also, I might try temporarily hard-coding the Gmail creds to make sure they're what you think they are.

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions that worked for me is by allowing "less secure apps" from my google account.

Steps to do this are as follow:-

From your Google Account settings, find "Sign In & Security" -> "Allow less secure apps", enable it.

Reference - https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255