# Sending emails through Gmail SMTP with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, gmail

Should those messages show up in my normal Gmail outbox?

Does this console output mean that it's been successful or what:

[image]

[image]

### Edit

[image]

Comment: They should show up in the outbox for the email being used. The console stuff means that your code is executing correctly, so the code side of it is working, however the email could still fail to reach it's destination because of gmail (failed validation or something).

Comment: but I don't see them in the outbox :/ and they never arrive

Comment: is it production or local?

Comment: I don't know- I'm running it on my local machine, localhost:3000

Comment: this might help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25872389/rails-4-how-to-correctly-configure-smtp-settings-gmail

Comment: ok- I'll try it- thank you

Comment: do you know how I can wipe all those emails out of my db? I'm running out of new ones :/

Comment: Without knowing exactly how you have this setup I am not sure.  What I would say is type "rake routes" into you console.  Is there a route that you can go to to view all of them?  If so go there and there may be a delete button which should delete them depending on how you have this setup.  Is there a specific tutorial or something you are working from?

Comment: this one https://launchschool.com/blog/handling-emails-in-rails

Comment: but it's not so good- and now I've been tweaking my settings

Comment: I added the output of `rake routes` to the op

Comment: is there a particular tutorial that you would recommend?

Comment: Oh, you need to delete users to get more emails to use, not the actual emails, those are not being saved anywhere.  that would be a different question.  I would search for a way to list and delete users based on the db you are using (probably sqlite3?)

Comment: yeah sqlite3 thats right- but- do you know a good tutorial?

Comment: like this I think `rails db:migrate:reset`

Comment: this is what I used, but it is for a service called sendgrid,  I personally found gmail to be unreliable due to authentication once it went up to heroku, my login was always getting denied so I switched to using this.  Best of luck ! https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/rubyonrails.html

Comment: Check out the letter_opener gem. It will show you in the browser the text of the email so you can check out the wording, the links, etc. I'm wondering why there's an image behind your log output; makes the log pretty hard to read. If that isn't your log output, you've wired up something with a "=" that wasn't needed. (<%= ... %> will output while <% ... %> will only prepare for output.

Comment: In response to your comment regarding emails "I'm running out of new ones :/". You can use a single email but use a + sign for uniqueness - e.g. dave+1@gmail.com, dave+2@gmail.com, etc... all those will actually be addressed to dave@gmail.com. To guarantee uniqueness use a GUID after the + (For development I auto generate these email addresses to save me filling it in each time)